# How to disable (hide) weekday in gnome-shell (GNOME 3.x) clock?

Tags: gnome, customization, clock

I can't find a way to remove weekday name from clock applet in gnome-shell, is it possible without editing the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I case you've missed it in comments, here are two patches:

#### Hide weekday

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=669778

#### Custom format

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=669782

However, they need a verification on the latest version of GNOME since I'm no longer using it.

Answer (score 5):

Two answers to your original question:

For **Unity**, choosing '**Ubuntu**' at the login screen **you can** do it:

1. Click on the time and select 'Time and date settings'
2. Select the 'Clock' tab
3. Un-check 'Weekday'

[image: time settings]

For **Gnome 3**, choosing '**Gnome**' at the login screen **you cannot** do it:

The setting does not exist as the screenshot shows below.

[image: gnome settings]

Best bet may be a [Gnome 3 extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/), or a bug report.

Comment: It looks like you are talking about old Unity that was based on GNOME 2.x. But gnome-shell is GNOME 3.x (and Unity from 11.10 is based on it) and there is no such settings unfortunately.

Comment: You are partially correct, the Gnome 3 desktop does not have this setting. The current Unity desktop does still have this feature. I'll edit my answer to match your newly edited question.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using GNOME 3.x then you can adjust clock setting using `gnome-tweak-tool`. However, you can take out the the date but not the day (i.e. Sat cannot be changed so far as I can tell)!

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

You can also look in g-settings via a terminal:

```
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.shell.clock
gsettings set  org.gnome.shell.clock show-date false
gsettings set  org.gnome.shell.clock show-date true
```

which gives only two options: `show-date` or `show-seconds`!
Or you can open up the configuration editor, then open "org" - "shell" and you will see calendar and clock which you can change manually.

When you open the Tweak Tool and go to Top Bar, you will see the option for showing/hiding the date:

[image: gnome3 tweak tool top bar hide date]

Comment: I was just looking through the Gnome-shell calendar.js and don't see an easy fix! even if you play with the code you will have to manually change it everytime there is a GS update !

Comment: Just what I feared. So we need a bugreport and a patch.. Thanks a lot! :) I hope I will try to find/make one tomorrow, but if someone will do it faster, do share a link :)

Comment: Did you notice const CLOCK_FORMAT_KEY on line 18? Looks promising, but I'm writing from my phone, will check later.

Comment: hmmm i will also take a look :-)

Comment: No, it's in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/dateMenu.js` **_updateClockAndDate** function. I will try to rewrite it.

Comment: And it was not fixed in the master branch: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/js/ui/dateMenu.js#n168

Comment: Ok, done. Now all we need is a custom format support. I will also add it but in different patch. Making the first one.

Comment: Here it is, you can try it yourself: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=669778

Comment: And here is custom format support: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=669782

Comment: i was just reading the links in bugzilla and wondering if they will do this world clock! would be useful. will have a play with your patch a little later on, is it compiled for G-S 3.3.5 ?

Comment: it was done on 3.2, but it looks like **_updateClockAndDate** function hadn't changed in master branch.